# Correctly inferring types when chaining observables

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Angular2 app that has a service that fetches a list of items. There is a method to also fetch more specific information for each item in the list. My current setup is:

```
// service for item list
class ItemsService {
  fetchItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get(url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
  fetchItemsWithData(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.fetchItems()
    .flatMap((items: Observable<Item[]>) => items)
    .map((item: Item) => this.itemService.fetchData(item))
    .flatMap((items: Observable<Item[]>) => items)
    .toArray();
  }
}

// service for individual items
class ItemService {
  fetchData(item: Item) {
    return this.http.get(`${url}/${item.id}`)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

This actually works exactly as I need it to even though the array <=> observable seems a little funky, but it does end up giving me an observable of an array of items with all of the item information.

The problem is, on the `return this.fetchItems()` line I always get:

> ```
> The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage.
> Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>   Type argument candidate 'Item[]' is not a valid type argument because it is not a
>   supertype of candidate 'Observable<Item[]>'.
>     Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<Item[]>'.
> ```

I'm at a bit of a loss since `fetchItems` does return an `Observable` and changing it to `Observable<any>` gives the same error. If I just change it to `any` though I don't get any error reports at all.

Is there a better type to use for `fetchItems`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspicious this might have something to do with `toArray()` which returns `Observable<T[]>`.

In your case where you define `fetchItems(): Observable<Item[]>` it makes `toArray()` to return `Observable<Observable<Item[]>[]>` so that's why it throws an error even with `Observable<any>`.

Btw I tried to simulate your situation with just mock classes and it compiled without errors (TypeScript 2.0.3) but maybe I made an error somewhere and its not identical (?):

```
class Observable<T> {
    map(_): Observable<T> { return new Observable<T>() }
    flatMap(_): Observable<T> { return new Observable<T>() }
    toArray(): Observable<T[]> { return new Observable<T[]>() }
}
class Item { }
class Response {
    json() { }
}
class HTTP {
    get(_) { return new Observable() }
}


class ItemsService {
    itemService = new ItemService();
    http = new HTTP();

    fetchItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.http.get('url').map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

    fetchItemsWithData(): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.fetchItems()
            .flatMap((items: Observable<Item[]>) => items)
            .map((item: Item) => this.itemService.fetchData(item))
            .flatMap((items: Observable<Item[]>) => items)
            .toArray();
    }
}

// service for individual items
class ItemService {
    http = new HTTP();

    fetchData(item: Item) {
        return this.http.get('url')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

When I ran into same issue, the reason was that I forgot to import `Response` class:

`import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';`

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Fsck! that just happened to me and it happened since I came to trust WebStorm too much - WebStorm didn't add it automatically, and I didn't even check that... :-)

Comment: @BoazRymland yep, that's strange that it doesn't even warn about using the class that is not imported

Answer (score 0):

Try adding returned type info to your maps and change your array annotations:

1. Instead of `Item[]`, use `Array<Item>`.
2. `fetchData(item: Item): ItemData` and `.map((item: Item): ItemData => this.itemService.fetchData(item))`